# Trying to figure out a $watch on data from a service

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a service to 'maintain' the current object a user is working on in my small angular app. I'm running into an issue where the watch I am using is not firing and I'm not exactly sure why. I've found multiple examples of using a function as your watch expression, but have yet to get one working. I've setup a simple fiddle with a service and controller here:

```
$scope.$watch('$foo.getCurrent()', function (nn, oo, scope) {
    scope.currentFoo = $foo.getCurrent();
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/risingfish/n2Bjp/36/)

The clear button is suppose to 'reset' the current object, which through the $watch, should reset the form back to an empty state. Could some smack the back of my head and tell what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated your fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/n2Bjp/37/

Don't think you want the scope being passed in the function that gets triggered and used a function for the first argument of the $watch call.

```
$scope.$watch(function() {return $foo.getCurrent()}, function (nn, oo) {
    $scope.currentFoo = $foo.getCurrent();
}, true);
```

Believe when using a string that only works for properties that can be resolved on the controller scope.  In any case using the function as the first parameter returning the thing you want to check always works (just don't do this if the checking of the thing changes it).

Comment: OH, ok, I see. That makes sense. Using your fiddle, I streamlined it slightly but it has the same effect. Thanks!  http://jsfiddle.net/risingfish/n2Bjp/39/